# Zakat on Savings for future house building

Tags: zakat

I have received my Retirement Benefits which I have kept in a FD at a Bank. This money I intend to use it for building my house for me and my family to live in. Is Zakat applicable on this amount. Please reply. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is zakatable once it reaches the nisab and is in your possession for one hawl (lunar year).